# UITabbar jumps when segueing to a controller without a tabbar after modal presentation on iPhone X

Tags: swift, uitabbar

I have a Master-Detail application with a tab bar on the Master Controller screen and I have a problem with iPhone X. When I segue from the Master to the Detail, everything works fine. If I show a modal window from the Master first and then go to the Detail, the tab bar freezes with the wrong size for a while. If I fix the tab bar size, everything animates fine. With this, for example:

```
class MyTabBar: UITabBar {
    var tabBarHeight: CGFloat = 83

    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        let superSize = super.sizeThatFits(size)
        return CGSize(width: superSize.width, height: self.tabBarHeight)
    }
}
```

However, I don't want to fix the size, as it's too complicated to manage all possible sizes and orientations.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution:

```
class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) { [weak self] in
            self?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```